# Android realm exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Object is no longer valid to operate on. Was it deleted by another thread?

Tags: android, realm

I am having the following issue in my code while using Realm for database.
**java.lang.IllegalStateException: Object is no longer valid to operate on. Was it deleted by another thread?**

I googled a lot for solution but couldn't find solution for my situation. That's why pasting my code here now. I have a recycler view based list of orders. An order list item has a button to change order status from picked up to delivered which is done by this method after successful order status update on server.

```
public void updateOrderStatus(final Order pOrder, final String newStatus) {

    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    if (realm != null && !realm.isClosed()) {

        realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                Order order = realm
                        .where(Order.class)
                        .equalTo("id", pOrder.id)
                        .findFirst();
                order.status = newStatus;
            }
        });
    }
 }
```

The following method is being called from a service who has a handler to run a task after some delay. That tasks gets all the delivered orders from server to mark orders as delivered which can't be marked delivered manually through a button on list because for some orders status update button is not available. These orders will be marked delivered by the app. On receiving all delivered order, service first updates the database which also updates the order that was previously marked delivered using above method in database as well. And secondly, deletes all the delivered orders.

```
public void deleteDeliveredOrders() {
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    if (realm != null && !realm.isClosed()) {

        realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {

                RealmResults<Order> orderRealmResults = realm
                        .where(Order.class)
                        .equalTo("status", Constants.OrderStatus.DELIVERED)
                        .findAll();

                orderRealmResults.deleteAllFromRealm();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

But when this method calls, app throws mentioned error and crashes. But I literally don't know why. I have searched a lot but no avail. Please guide what am I doing wrong.

Thanks,
momersaleem

Comment: If you add where you actually get the exception, that might help answer the question.

Comment: But one tip I can give is that you're using `RealmResults` without adding a `RealmChangeListener` to it so that it could update the adapter when the data changes.